# How to install Qt4 in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, qt

I tried to use Qt5 but I have some problems while making Debian packaging process with Qt5 so I would like to have Qt4 on Ubuntu 12.10. How can I install Qt4.

Comment: Have you tried installing from [USC](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/qtcreator/)

Answer (score 23):

Just download Qt-4.8 from here and run the self-installer

http://qt-project.org/downloads

or install it from ubuntu software center (two package)

qt-sdk

qt creator

Comment: I installed qt using software center but I only get qt creator and not libs, but if I download qt4 from link you posted I get only libs which I need to compile, and that takes really too much time.

Comment: By installing "qt-sdk" from software center you will get all libs and I`ve just downloaded "qt-linux-opensource-5.0.1-x86-offline.run" one weak ago you just download the 4.8 and double click it to install.

Comment: Download these two files    -   http://releases.qt-project.org/qt4/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4.tar.gz         -        http://releases.qt-project.org/qt5/5.0.1/qt-linux-opensource-5.0.1-x86-offline.run

Comment: I installed Qt5 already but there is no install file for Qt4 libs which I downloaded from your link, I have to compile it but it takes too much time.

Comment: Also you can install libs from software center by installing "qt-sdk"

Comment: I installed qt-sdk already but I can't find those libs. When I try to compile simple hello world program I only get option to compile it using Qt5.

Comment: I have installed the same packages and there is no problem to compile programs. I don't know what to say?

Comment: There is no such thing as Qt-sdk in software center